# TypeError from Python 3 async for loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5

I'm learning about Python's relatively new async features. I found this in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#example-2):

> The following is a utility class that transforms a regular iterable to
>   an asynchronous one. While this is not a very useful thing to do, the
>   code illustrates the relationship between regular and asynchronous
>   iterators.
>
> ```
> class AsyncIteratorWrapper:
>     def __init__(self, obj):
>         self._it = iter(obj)
>
>     def __aiter__(self):
>         return self
>
>     async def __anext__(self):
>         try:
>             value = next(self._it)
>         except StopIteration:
>             raise StopAsyncIteration
>         return value
>
> async for letter in AsyncIteratorWrapper("abc"):
>     print(letter)
> ```

I attempted to run this code, by adding the given `async for` loop to a function, and then calling that using an event loop.

Full example code (run in the interpreter):

```
class AsyncIteratorWrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._it = iter(obj)
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            value = next(self._it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        return value

async def aprint(str):
  async for letter in AsyncIteratorWrapper(str):
    print(letter)

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
co = aprint("abcde")
loop.run_until_complete(co)
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 337, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in aprint
TypeError: 'async for' received an invalid object from __aiter__: AsyncIteratorWrapper
```

What am I doing wrong? How can this example be fixed? I'm a little surprised that code right out of the PEP is failing.

I'm using python version 3.5.1.

Comment: It is working on `python3.6`

Comment: Working on 3.5 too - Taking a look at the change log I found "Changed in version 3.5.2: Starting with CPython 3.5.2, __aiter__ can directly return asynchronous iterators. "

Comment: for a few versions in 3.5 `__aiter__` was suppose to be async but then the symantics changed to directly return the async iterable, so just update to a more recent version of python and you should be fine.

Comment: @Orange would you mind linking to that so I don't have to go through the trouble of finding it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-492-coroutines-with-async-and-await-syntax

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks! If someone wants to write these comments up into a well-written answer, I'll mark it as "the answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using works with python 3.5.2+.

From Python 3.5.2 `__aiter__`  can directly return asynchronous iterators. [More here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-492-coroutines-with-async-and-await-syntax)

The error you were receiving was because of the older python(3.5.1) and it was therefore returning the wrong type.