# How does FastAPI's application mounting works?

Tags: python, plugins, middleware, fastapi, starlette

For certain reasons, we have chosen the [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), in order to use it as back-end tier of our multi-module production. One of its attractive features is sub application, that helps us to separate different modules with intention of making it more modular. But we are ***concerned*** about some possible deficiencies which are missing in the official documentation. There are a considerable amount of common things -- e.g data, services, etc -- that we need to share them between main module and submodule through plugins, middle-wares and dependency-injection. The questions are: **Is this feature good enough for separate modules?** and so: **Do sub applications inherit middle-ware, plugins and dependency injection from parent app?**

*thanks for sharing your experiences.*

[the sample code in the official docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/app")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from main app"}


subapi = FastAPI()


@subapi.get("/sub")
def read_sub():
    return {"message": "Hello World from sub API"}


app.mount("/subapi", subapi)
```

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76057623/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528465/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### I think documentation is pretty clear about it.

> "Mounting" means adding a completely "independent" application.

Whatsoever, let's keep going from your example.

This is what we got for our subapi's routes.

```
[{"path":route.path} for route in subapi.routes] = [
     {'path': '/openapi.json'},
     {'path': '/docs'},
     {'path': '/docs/oauth2-redirect'},
     {'path': '/redoc'},
     {'path': '/sub'}
     ]
```

This is what we got for app's routes.

```
[{"path":route.path} for route in app.routes] = [{'path': '/openapi.json'},
     {'path': '/docs'},
     {'path': '/docs/oauth2-redirect'},
     {'path': '/redoc'},
     {'path': '/app'},
     {'path': '/subapi'}
     ]
```

That's quite interesting because our subapi did not inherited `/app`, let's keep going and make things more interesting, let us run our app with a single command

```
uvicorn my_app_name:app
```

- As expected we have our app's documentation in `/docs`
- Also we have subapi's documentation in `/subapi/docs`, there is not interesting here.

So what we should expect, when we add this?

```
subapi.mount("/app", app)
```

Let's run it again, but this time let's call subapi.

```
uvicorn my_app_name:subapi
```

What do we expect to see?

- **By default we should have subapi's documentation in `/docs`**
- **The app's documentation in the `/app/docs`**

Yes, we are right, but things goes interesting from here.

Now we have an application like Matryoshka dolls

When we send a request to `/app/subapi/sub` (Remind we ran our app with `uvicorn my_app_name:subapi`)

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/subapi/sub

Out: {"message":"Hello World from sub API"}
```

Seems like it's working fine but let's try more.

What about `/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/app`

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/subapi/app/app

Out: {"message":"Hello World from main app"}
```

Are you confused? Don't be, let me explain.

When you mount a sub-application, FastAPI takes care of the mounted app, using a mechanism from the ASGI specification called a `root_path`

What `root_path` does and why the example above worked?

Straight-forward `root_path` says, you can reach all the routes that you defined in your `app.routes` from your `root_path`, let's visualize this.

Now our `root_path` is `/app`

```
/app/
```

Let's add subapi, and it became our `root_path`.

```
/app/subapi/
```

Let's add app again, and it became our `root_path`

```
/app/subapi/app
```

- **Note:** The example above worked because, we mounted two apps together.

Are you not satisfied and you are saying what if I add a middleware, what is going to happen?

Easy to answer, it will not inherit.

Let me explain this with a simple example, I am going to add a middleware for my subapi.

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

subapi.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware)
```

All the data for your application is inside of `__dict__`

So we can find out the difference easily by checking the 'user_middleware' key.

```
subapi.__dict__['user_middleware'] = [Middleware(CORSMiddleware)]
app.__dict__['user_middleware'] = []
```

All the other things you add etc will work independently because they are totally different applications underneath, so you will use mounting safely.

### Conclusion

- Yes, they will **work independently.**

Comment: thanks a lot for your complete answer. I could lesson more than what I asked from your  answer indeed. it seems I should pack my dependancies in order to inject them in each of sub apps separately.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad it helped. Yes it's pretty useful in some cases, I don't exactly know what is your use case but, it seems you want to use a lot of  middleware and dependency injection, maybe you should consider creating your own [APIRouter class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117827/13161155)

Comment: It seems good suggestion. it can integrate most of middle wares I will try ti out. thanks once more.