# Mounting Flask app in FastAPI raises a 404 Not Found error response

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404, fastapi

I mounting a flask app on FastAPI with `WSGIMiddleware` and I want root `"/"` to be my flask app and `"/api"` to be a FastAPI route. Here is my code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware
from flask import Flask

fastapi = FastAPI()

app = Flask(__name__)

fastapi.mount("/", WSGIMiddleware(app=app))
```

i run it with uvicorn :

```
from app import fastapi
import uvicorn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(fastapi)
```

this is my route for test for api and flask app :

```
@fastapi.get("/api")
def test():
    return {"hello": "world"}

@app.get("/")
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world"
```

Flask part is working perfectly fine, but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api I get a `404 Not Found` error response. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to make sure to `mount` the Flask app **at the end** of the code, as demonstrated in the example given in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/#using-wsgimiddleware). The reason is simply because the **order** in which the endpoints are defined **matters**, as endpoints are evaluated in order (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) for more details and examples).

##### [What is "Mounting"](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#what-is-mounting)

> "Mounting" means adding a complete "independent" application in a
> specific path, that **then takes care of handling all the sub-paths**.
>
> This is different from using an `APIRouter` as a mounted application
> is completely independent. The OpenAPI and docs from your main
> application won't include anything from the mounted application, etc.

Thus, since you are mounting the Flask app under the path `/`, every request under that path **will be handled by the Flask application**, while the rest will be handled by FastAPI. Hence, the `404 Not Found` error response when trying to hit the `/api` endpoint. This response actually comes from the Flask app, since it does not include a `/api` endpoint. So, you need to define the `/api` endpoint from FastAPI app **before** mounting the Flask app, as shown in the example given below. If you mounted the Flask app under a different path, such as `/v1`, that would not interfere with any of FastAPI's endpoints, you could still mount the Flask app in the way you currently do.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware
from flask import Flask, escape, request

flask_app = Flask(__name__)


@flask_app.route("/")
def flask_main():
    name = request.args.get("name", "World")
    return f"Hello, {escape(name)} from Flask!"


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/api")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


app.mount("/", WSGIMiddleware(flask_app))
```