# i have problem with deploying and flask app that mounted on fast api on cpanel

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, fastapi, passenger

I have a flask app that mounted on fastapi like this :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
`from flask import Flask
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware

fastapi = FastAPI()
app = Flask(__name__)
fastapi.mount("/", WSGIMiddleware(app=app))
```

i try to run it in passenger_wsgi with following command but its dosent work how can i deploy my project ?

```
from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware
from app import fastapi  

application = ASGIMiddleware(fastapi)
```

Comment: why are you mixing flask and fastapi? seems like a weird thing to do...

Comment: i wanyt to have a ready to use docs for my api session thats why i mix flask with fastapi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mounting Flask app in FastAPI raises a 404 Not Found error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057185/mounting-flask-app-in-fastapi-raises-a-404-not-found-error-response)

Comment: this was my question and you help me to fix it now my applicatin works fine on local but now i want to deploy it and i have cpanel and i cant run it there i get following error in my log file [UID:2371][4893] Child process with pid: 5062 was killed by signal: 15, core dumped: no