# FastAPI/Starlette middleware returns a StreamingResponse instead of JSONResponse

Tags: fastapi, starlette

I am trying to write a FastAPI middleware to add a header to a response. The contents of the header is based on the value of the response body. This is what I have so far:

```
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware

class FooMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
        response = await call_next(request)
        response.headers["X-Foo"] = Foo(response.content)
        return response
```

According to the docs, FastAPI returns JSON responses as a default (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=stream#jsonresponse), and I have done nothing to override that.

The strange thing is that the type of the response object seems to be `StreamingResponse` (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=stream#streamingresponse). What is causing that?

Comment: This seems odd, but without the code of the endpoint, it is difficoult to say anything. Do you mind sharing it?

Comment: Any response inside of the _middleware_ will be a StreamingResponse: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/040d8c86b09f34be49e8c253d97a588973bc7308/starlette/middleware/base.py#L98 - as this is what `call_next` returns. I'm guessing when you get this far any response has been converted to a read that can be awaited. Your middleware shouldn't depend on the _response type_ itself returned from your view.

Comment: @MatsLindh How would I go about awaiting the (async generator type) `response.body_iterator`? I've tried awaiting it, which is an error.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/874 (and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115628/get-starlette-request-body-in-the-middleware-context - they're generally the same problem) ?

Comment: See [relate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) as well.